# How to animate with background-blend-mode like with overlays?

Tags: css, blending

### EDIT

There seems to be no issue with the code. It's only CodePen that fails to show the animation correctly.

## ORIGINAL QUESTION

A normal solution for my problem would be absolutely position an overlay container with semi-transparent background (color, linear-gradient, radial-gradient, conic-gradient or even url(image)). In case of the image you would likely combine it with opacity.

There's a newer [well supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=background-blend-mode) CSS property called `background-blend-mode` which (without animation) does the same, but in different ways.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
div {
  --sqrt2: 1.4142135623730950488016887242097;
  --size: 300px;
  --x: 0%;
  --y: 0%;
  margin: auto;
  height: var(--size);
  width: var(--size);
  
  background: url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/695/800/600.jpg?hmac=TL1K4j89C4vOeDFLlzW0-BaQ2RQMMPW_4W3bW62nChM), radial-gradient(circle calc(var(--size) * var(--sqrt2)) at var(--x) var(--y), lightblue 0%, lightblue 20%, lightgreen 40%, lightcoral 60%, lightyellow 80%, lightyellow 100%);
  background-blend-mode: luminosity; /* normal | multiply | screen | overlay | darken | lighten | color-dodge | color-burn | hard-light | soft-light | difference | exclusion | hue | saturation | color | luminosity */
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Now the problem is when one tries to animate the `radial-gradient` (in this case). In a "normal" case, one simply animates the gradients coordinates and it looks good. In the case of `background-blend-mode` it failed me though.

I don't think I did anything wrong and this is perhaps just a bug in CSS, so asking for advice here might be in vain, but perhaps someone still has advice.

You may play around with my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/S3C_MM/pen/zYzROpw) or just checkout the snippet here:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
@property --x {
  syntax: "<percentage>";
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: 0%;
}
@property --y {
  syntax: "<percentage>";
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: 0%;
}
div {
  --sqrt2: 1.4142135623730950488016887242097;
  --size: 300px;
  --x: 0%;
  --y: 0%;
  margin: auto;
  height: var(--size);
  width: var(--size);
  
  background: url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/695/800/600.jpg?hmac=TL1K4j89C4vOeDFLlzW0-BaQ2RQMMPW_4W3bW62nChM), radial-gradient(circle calc(var(--size) * var(--sqrt2)) at var(--x) var(--y), lightblue 0%, lightblue 20%, lightgreen 40%, lightcoral 60%, lightyellow 80%, lightyellow 100%);
  background-blend-mode: luminosity; /* normal | multiply | screen | overlay | darken | lighten | color-dodge | color-burn | hard-light | soft-light | difference | exclusion | hue | saturation | color | luminosity */
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-animation: roundabout 30s infinite ease-in-out both;
  -moz-animation: roundabout 30s infinite ease-in-out both;
  -o-animation: roundabout 30s infinite ease-in-out both;
  animation: roundabout 30s infinite ease-in-out both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes roundabout {
  100%, 0% { --x: 0%; --y: 0% }
  25% { --x: 100%; --y: 0% }
  50% { --x: 100%; --y: 100% }
  75% { --x: 0%; --y: 100% }
}
@-moz-keyframes roundabout {
  100%, 0% { --x: 0%; --y: 0% }
  25% { --x: 100%; --y: 0% }
  50% { --x: 100%; --y: 100% }
  75% { --x: 0%; --y: 100% }
}
@-o-keyframes roundabout {
  100%, 0% { --x: 0%; --y: 0% }
  25% { --x: 100%; --y: 0% }
  50% { --x: 100%; --y: 100% }
  75% { --x: 0%; --y: 100% }
}
@keyframes roundabout {
  100%, 0% { --x: 0%; --y: 0% }
  25% { --x: 100%; --y: 0% }
  50% { --x: 100%; --y: 100% }
  75% { --x: 0%; --y: 100% }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Hm.. posting here it actually works in the snippet as expected. Apparently it's just a CodePen issue. Am I in breach of any SO regulations, if I just leave this here for anyone who may have the same problem?

Comment: codepen and snippets works fine with chrome, not with firefox :(

Comment: Weirdly I had the issue in Chrome, but ever since I posted this, the CodePen works fine in it. Just tested with firefox as well, and while blend mode works perfectly, the animation is lost.

Answer (score 0):

The non-prefixed CSS property is incorrect, it should be **animation** instead of animate. The prefixed properties are correct though.

<s>animate: roundabout 30s infinite ease-in-out both;</s>

animation: roundabout 30s infinite ease-in-out both;

Comment: Fixed in the question. Thanks. This could easily be a comment though. (Also, this did not fix animation in Firefox, sadly)